# Microsoft graph change azure ad b2c user password not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to reset users password through Microsoft Graph, the code runs but the user password is not changed. my code is based on the following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

```
  string GeneratedPassword = "Testing@12345";
        //GeneratedPassword = letterOne + PasswordGenerator.Generate(8, 3) + $"{letterTwo}{NumberOne}";

        var currentUser = users.Where(x => x.Mail == accountEmail).ToArray();

        if (currentUser.Length!=0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser[0].Id);
            try
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                    {
                        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                        Password = GeneratedPassword
                    }

                };


                var response = graphServiceClient.Users[currentUser[0].Id]
                    .Request()
                    .UpdateAsync(user);



            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the correct delegated permissions set for the user that is doing the request ?  Also please add the await keyword like Ali said in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More detail is required to fully understand the issue, such as the response you are getting. Is there any error?

However, I noticed that you did not use the "**await**" keyword.

Try this:

```
var response = await graphServiceClient.Users[currentUser[0].Id]
                .Request()
                .UpdateAsync(user);
```

Most likely your user "UpdateAsync(user)" operation is not being executed because you are not awaiting the "Request()" operation. So, the update never happens.

Again, much more detail is required to fully understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I missed the await operator, now I got the error, previouse it was not showing the error. I need to update the user administrator role also. so now it works